# gd library watermark in png image

Tags: php, png, gdlib

I'm trying to watermark images, but when the image is in PNG format, the watermark loses transparency.

```
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('logo.png');

                $watermarkWidght = imagesx($watermark);
                $watermarkHeigth = imagesy($watermark);

                $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);

                $imageWidght = imagesx($imagenss);
                $imageHeigth = imagesy($imagenss);

                $positionX = ($imageWidght) - ($watermarkWidght);
                $positiony = ($imageHeigth) - ($watermarkHeigth);
imagealphablending($image , true); // set alpha
imagesavealpha($image , true);
 

                imagecopy($imagenss, $watermark, (int)$positionX, (int)$positiony,0,0, $watermarkWidght,$watermarkHeigth);
                ob_start();
                imagepng($imagenss);
                $ImageData=ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
```

[PNG image with watermark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj64R.png)

The watermark should maintain transparency when the background image is in .png format.
When it comes to an image in .jpg format, the watermark maintains transparency.

Comment: do you mean this? https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php